# I have problems with instalation of root (cern) in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: cmake, root-framework

I follow the steps described in this page: https://techforcurious.website/cern-root-installation-ubuntu-18-04-enabling-libraries/ but when i place `cmake ../root-6.10.04/ -Dall=ON` appears the next error:

```
CMake Error at cmake/modules/SearchInstalledSoftware.cmake:825 (message):
  The Alien plugin requires option 'xrootd' to be enabled.  Re-run the
  configuration with 'xrootd=ON'
```

I re-run the configuration with `xrootd=ON` and appears:

```
 Set environment variable XRDSYS to point to your XROOTD installation
 Alternatively, you can also enable the option 'builtin_xrootd' to build XROOTD internally.
```

Help me please.

Comment: Did you try enabling the suggested option or installing xrootd, whatever that may be?

Comment: I already installed xrootd but it does not work, really i dont know what happens with that form of installation. But I already managed to install it in another way.

Comment: for reference: http://xrootd.org/ (in short for root to be able to open files over the network). @ErikGarcia did you, aside from installing xrootd, also set the XRDSYS environment variable? (i.e. `export XRDSYS=/path/to/the/xrootd/installation` before running cmake)

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the ROOT installation [instructions](https://root.cern/install/). You can use a precompiled binary for your Ubuntu version and you should not have any problems with this.